# how it's possible that JSONObject put (String name, long value) can store int64 value in json?

Tags: java, android, json

I don't understand how can work `JSONObject put (String name, long value)` because actually json permit only to store float value on 8 bit. Of course we can store big number, but more bigger the number is, more inaccurate will be the value stored in json. for exemple it's not possible to store in float of 8 bit this exact value: 18,446,744,073,709,551,614, when we will try to retrieve the value we will receive something like 18,446,744,073,700,000,000

so i m curious, what exactly do JSONObject put (String name, long value) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is incorrect. Length of numbers in JSON is not limited. Limitations are in different implementations. For example abominatin called javascript is limited to floats (programming language without integers, what a great idea!) JSONObject in android has no issues storing and retrieving long integer values.

Comment: ok i understand, but not completely, because in json text file, their is no flag to say if a value is float, integer or int64. For exemple 1234 can be all of them. So how it's can work when you save the json to a file and load it again later ?

Comment: Again, this depends on implentation. Android JSONObject implementation simply first tries parse value as integral type (long or int if small enough), if this fails then tries parse value as double and if this also fails treats value as  unquoted string.